# What is the "Count" column in the order book on Bitfinex?

Tags: terminology, exchange-order, bitfinex

[image]

I can't understand what count means here. I would have assumed that it was the number of orders at that price, but the total column does not seem to reflect this. Can't find any info in the documentation or glossary. Thanks

Comment: Count refers to the total numbers of orders. 1 means only one order at that price level, 15 would mean there are 15 orders at that price level.

Answer (score 4):

It's because the `Total` column is not the cumulate sum of the column `Count` but of the column `Amount`. In your example, at the line for price `1612`, `Total=6.0` and indeed if you do the sum of all amount of the price above `1612` it gives you : `0.3+1.2+1.7+2.8 = 6`

Answer (score 1):

Count:

This is the total number of orders at that level. A count of 1 means that 1 order is at that price point. A count of 6 would mean that there are 6 orders at that price point.

From https://support.bitfinex.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003284889-Order-Book-Terms